# Disable interaction on transparent view without affecting its subviews and buttons

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoa-touch, uiview

I want to make a floating menu in a view that will be later added to many tab view  view controllers. So I want the view itself to be transparent and doesn't receive interactions while keeping users able to interact with the menu buttons.

As in the picture below:

[image]

I tried to set the view alpha to 0, it  cascaded down to all its subviews.

Tried to set userInteractionEnabled to NO it did  cascade down to all subviews as well.

Any suggestions??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a *custom view* and `override` the `pointInside:`, it returns `false` when the point isn't within an eligible child view.

**It could look like this:**

```
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    for subview in subviews {
        if !subview.hidden, subview.userInteractionEnabled, subview.frame.contains(point) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Hi @Jakub. How can I make this work for a UIContainerView